# How to guide a color transfer process between 2 images using colored mask images to separate regions?

Tags: python, histogram, mask, image-segmentation, transfer

Currently I have this code which transfer color from one image, to another image: https://github.com/ProGamerGov/Neural-Tools/blob/master/linear-color-transfer.py

The code works by transferring the color from one image, to another image.

An example of a mask image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8145.png

And the associated regular image: https://i.imgur.com/Pl6WkL3.jpg

How would I guide my color transfer process between 2 images using colored mask images to separate regions? Assuming the number of regions in each mask may not be the same, and can have different colors, but only the regions with the same color in their mask image will have their color transfer and applied.